# how to call a jQuery function in php

Tags: php, jquery

```
 if($this->db->insert(table,$insert_array))
{?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#div1').show().delay(15000).fadeOut('fast');
})
</script>

    <?php   
}
```

I want to call this function $('#div1').show().delay(15000).fadeOut('fast'); if my if statement is true. Kindly help

Comment: remaining code works fine. i m not able to write the complete code here so this is the only part where i am having problem.

Comment: put a space in { ?> in this line if($this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array))
{?> and check is it working?

Comment: if you add `var_dump( $this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array) )`, what is the output?

Comment: my query is working fine. I mean whether i get the message displayed or not it will update my database.

Comment: var_dump( $this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array) )  shows nothing,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    if($this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array)) {
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('#div1').show().delay(15000).fadeOut('fast');
        </script>
<?php  
    }
?>
```

Comment: How is this different from the code the TS posts? I'm overseeing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
if($this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array))
{?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
     $('#div1').show().delay(15000).fadeOut('fast');
     })
  </script>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you write something like this:

```
<?php if($this->db->insert(TBL_CAR,$insert_sql_array)) :?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
          $('#div1').show().delay(15000).fadeOut('fast');
       })
    </script>

<?php endif ;?>
```

This should work perfectly well for you. I have implemented something of such on several ocassion

Comment: Use Ajax call for it then...I am sure you are using codeigniter right?